# Where can I download the latest version of the Yu-Gi-Oh pc game (if available)?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

It has been many years since the official Yu-Gi-Oh! Power of Chaos pc games were released. Did they release an update or a newer version which I am missing? If yes, where can I download (or purchase) it?

Comment: You seek Power of Chaos specifically, or the latest pc game for yugioh? Also, I *think* that maybe this isn't the best place to ask about this, as you are not asking about a Card Game *per se* but instead about a videogame of the franchise... perhaps this is better material for Arcade.SE? (I recall there is a meta post regarding the on-topicness of these sort of situations, will check it and update you)

Comment: Well... seems that this [answer](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/180/22373) suggests that digital versions of card games are on topic :)

Comment: [@DarkCygnus](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/22373/darkcygnus) I am just seeking for any Yu-Gi-Oh! PC game, not necessarily Power of Chaos.

Comment: Well, that is a different question than what you are asking. The current phrasing is fine IMO so perhaps consider leaving it that way (or asking other post), but surely asking that other question would be off-topic, as you are basically asking for a [game recommendation](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/22373), which happens to be off-topic.

Comment: @WaisKamal I play on [dueling book](https://www.duelingbook.com/)

Comment: @WhatsThePoint oh, so they renamed it from Dueling Network huh? Good place to play, although sometimes you find rage-quitters as not everyone used to know the rules well... or are the rulings now automatized?

Comment: @DarkCygnus yeah it got renamed, everything is still manual though, but I kinda prefer it that way as it’s like playing a game irl, however judges can be called or clarification of things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Wiki](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_Power_of_Chaos), Yu-Gi-Oh! Power of Chaos consisted on a series of three games, which were (in order of release):

- [Yugi the Destiny](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_Power_of_Chaos:_Yugi_the_Destiny)
- [Kaiba the Revenge](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_Power_of_Chaos:_Kaiba_the_Revenge)
- [Joey the Passion](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_Power_of_Chaos:_Joey_the_Passion)

Seems that there are no further releases of the Power of Chaos series.

As for where to download or buy there are several options, so the best would be to Google the specific release of POC you seek and chose among the options (I also want to refrain from promoting a specific page or product)

A quick search revealed several sites that offer download, and I am sure that you could find it on places like Amazon or EBay